# Create a single list from two data frames

Tags: r

I have two data frames:

```
  DF1
      e   l    u
      1   0.5  1.5
      2   1    3
      3   2    4

    DF2
    e    l       u
    0.1  0.01    0.15
    0.2  0.1     0.3
    0.3  0.2     0.4
```

I want to combine these two data frames into single list like so:

```
L
[[1]]
$e: [(1,0.1);(2,0.2);(3,0.3)]
$l: [(0.5,0.01);(1,0.1);(2,0.2)]
$u: [(1.5,0.015);(3,0.3);(4,0.4)]
```

I have tried to rbind two data frames and then split by same column, but it results in multiple lists not a single one.
Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try

```
 Map(function(x,y) do.call(paste, c(data.frame(x,y), sep=";")), DF1, DF2)
```

or

```
library(jsonlite)
Map(function(x,y) toJSON(cbind(x,y)), DF1, DF2)
#$e
#[[1,0.1],[2,0.2],[3,0.3]] 

#$l
#[[0.5,0.01],[1,0.1],[2,0.2]] 

#$u
#[[1.5,0.15],[3,0.3],[4,0.4]]
```

Comment: this function changes the class of bind variables, how can i preserve it?

Comment: @HoHoHo  It is because I pasted it, instead create a `list`.  You can do `Map(function(x,y) do.call(list, data.frame(x,y)), DF1, DF2)`

Comment: @HoHoHo  The expected output you showed seems to either `paste`d values or a `JSON` output.  That is the reason I showed both options